# Do Katniss' parents have a set name?

Tags: the-hunger-games, names

Does Katniss' mother have a known first name? What about her father?

I would prefer canonical sources, the movie and author interviews if any are okay.

Comment: A few minutes research suggests that they're not named in the books, nor have their names been revealed by the author or actors. The script and books simply list them as Mr and Mrs Everdeen. Obviously a lack of evidence isn't proof of anything, but I'd be surprised if you get an answer.

Comment: @Richard I didn't see anything either. That's why I though I'd ask!

Comment: Interesting question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I believe they do not have “canon” names.**

At least, they’re not named in the books, or any author interview or supplementary material that I can find.

The actress who plays Mrs. Everdeen, Paula Malcolmson, said [in an interview](http://www.etonline.com/movies/129123_Katniss_Mothers_Name_Paula_Malcomson_Interview_Catching_Fire/index.html) that she made up a first name for the character:

> In creating an elaborate backstory for her character, Malcomson also **created** a first name for her character. “I named her Clara,” she tells ETonline. “I don’t know why, but that just came to me.”

This sounds like Malcolmson came up with the name independent of Suzanne Collins. Since Collins was involved in the film production (she helped adapt the novel for the screen), I assume she’d tell Malcolmson if she had a name in mind. That she didn’t makes me inclined to think she probably didn’t give Katniss’s parents names, and so “Clara” is the best we have.

As for Mr. Everdeen, I think he’ll stay just that. The author has shown no interest in giving him a name, and he only appears in a brief flashback in the film, so I doubt the actor gave much thought to his first name.